# mysql: implement function into query

Tags: mysql, diacritics, querying

i'm having a database which is storing geo-data like countries, cities.
i would like to use modrewrite with links like:
mysite.com/europe/austria/vienna

now the problem: in german, some countries contain umlauts like austria = österreich
(i can't use umlauts in urls)

so my question:
is there a way to create a function inside the database which replaces all special characters when querying like "where validUrl(country)='oesterreich' ?
which would replace ö->oe

my only idea so far is adding an extra database field for modrewrite which would hold "oesterreich"

any ideas? thanks

Comment: So ö->oe always, or just for German?  And for other languages / accents?

Comment: it should be a global function for all queries where i can replace all special characters ..

Comment: @Ben, 63% doesn't look bad, Fuxi just wants `correct` answers nothing wrong with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function in MySQL like so

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION UmlautRaus(input varchar) RETURNS varchar
BEGIN
  declare output varchar;

  SET output = REPLACE(input,'ü','ue');
  SET output = REPLACE(output,.....
  ....
  RETURN output;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

However as @GolezTrol said, this is not a great idea because of diacritics in other languages.

Link: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html

Comment: thanks it's what i needed! :))
i don't care about other languages as i only need it for the purpose described above. where can i get more info on string manipulations like string to lowercase?

Answer (score 1):

It won't help you, because though you can replace ü with ue in German, you can't do such things with diacritics in other languages. You can however encode these characters so they are valid in the url. See [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) and urldecode for this.

Also, when you set the collation of the column to unicode_ci, you should be able to select similar strings, so `WHERE YourField = 'enquête'` should match 'enquete' too. 'österreich' will probably match 'osterreich' but not 'oesterreich'. MySQL is probably not smart enough to know whether this word is French or German.

You could choose a specifically german collation, but this won't suit your goal. It may still be interesting to read [this text on collations](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-collation-effect.html), since it shows the difference between two german collations.